# batch script: recursivle renaming files with multiple extensions

Tags: batch-file, batch-rename

so to make myself a little more clear

```
file1.ext1.ext2 >>  file1.ext2
file2.ext3.ext4 >>  file2.ext4
...
           ->rename to->
```

I'm trying to achieve this with a for loop but I am stuck

```
for %%i in (c:/) do ren %%i.??? to %%~ni.???
```

any could give me a hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
@echo off
for %%a in (file*) do (
    for %%f in ("%%~na") do (
        ECHO ren %%~a %%~nf%%~xa
    )
)
```